# Show document date instead of upload date in Sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I've uploaded files to my sharepoint online (office 365), but all my files are "created on" the date of uploading. Is it possible to show the actual file creation date instead of the upload date?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to create a new date time column and populate that information then surface that field in the view. Going forward, the created date would be the same as what Sharepoint stores, but for historical files, you have to define that metadata yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem using an excellent tool SPFileZilla (https://spfilezilla.codeplex.com). Using this tool, the original file date of last modification is preserved, the item creation date is set to date of copying the file to Sharepoint. All without the need of any custom attributes, event receivers or a single line of code.